# Tokyo Luggage Storage For 1 Day

Tags: shopping, luggage-storage, tokyo, nrt, hnd

I am headed to Sydney and will be coming back home to the US via Tokyo. I arrive in Haneda in the morning and have an evening flight out of Narita. Naturally, I want to take the time to do some shopping in Tokyo but won't have a hotel where to store my bags. Does anyone have ideas for what I can do with 2 rolling suitcases while I go shopping in Tokyo?

I know there are services that will forward your bags to the airport but none of them do it same day, they need at least 1 day in advance. So this doesn't really seem to be a realistic option.

As an alternate, I will only realistically have time to visit 1-2 shopping centers. Can anyone recommend one that has a bag storage or some sort of security desk where I can leave my bags securely while I shop?

Comment: Luggage lockers in train stations may be an option. I struggle to assemble official sources with the time left today and so will leave this as a comment. Search keywords: JR Station Lockers.

Comment: @B.Liu Japanese train station lockers are too small to accommodate full-size suitcases. Large stations have manned luggage counters though.

Comment: Depends on the size of the suitcase. You can see locker dimensions here: https://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2274.html

Comment: IIRC Tokyo Station has a luggage storage service that's more available (although more expensive) than the lockers.

Comment: did you research any of these options: https://tokyo-haneda.com/en/service/facilities/baggage_checkroom.html